# React JS map data is not defined in axois

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

Basically, I started working on sample axois API,
In the console, the data is coming perfect, and once a compilation in command is done its not throwing any error, but in the browser, it showing `TypeError: data.map is not a function

Any Help will be appreciated !!`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Api() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://reqres.in/api/users/")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {data.map((e) => (
          <li key={e.id}>{e.email}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default Api;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

have done so far

Comment: are you sure that `response.data` is an array not JSON?

Comment: Got it thanks Amila I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten the dependecy array as the second parameter on useEffect.

useEffect(() => {
axios
.get("https://reqres.in/api/users/")
.then((response) => {
console.log(response);
setData(response.data);
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log(error);
});
}, []);